# Differences in later versions of bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In an article I was reading recently, published originally in 1996, the following code is quoted for a way in which to evaluate whether the directory $1 is stored in is writable:

```
    if [ ! -w `dirname $1` ]
    then
        echo $0: I will not be able to delete $1 for you.
        exit 1
    fi
```

'Learning the Bash Shell' *O'Reilly* - mentions that the use of grave accents (`) is now archaic. If this is the case, what would now be the standard way of performing this task?

Many thanks,

hcaw

Comment: You can find the GNU bash manual in various formats [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

Comment: The following link also gives a good explanation of the differences between ` and $() http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, now we use:

```
if [ ! -w $(dirname $1) ]
then
    echo $0: I will not be able to delete $1 for you.
    exit 1
fi
```

that is,

```
` `
```

syntax has been replaced by

```
$( )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, from now on I will try and consult only up-to-date manuals! hcaw

Comment: You should also wrap all file/path/whatever references in double-quotes, to prevent misparsing if they contain spaces or other shell metacharacters: `if [ ! -w "$(dirname "$1")" ]` and `echo "$0: I will not be able to delete $1 for you."`